# How to add a class to closest previous element in SVG using jQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

i have this kind of HTML:

```
<g>
    <path d="..." />
    <text class="abbr"></text>
</g>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$("text.abbr").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).closest("path").prev().attr("class", "active");
});
```

I know, SVG has a lot of limitations.
Please, help me to select closest previous element `path` (if i hover element `text`) using jQuery or JavaScript to add a class to element `path`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(this).closest("g").find('path').attr("class", "active");

Comment: Felix, it works! =) Danke!

Comment: Answer added for voting :)

Comment: I posted an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest` traverses the tree **up**, i.e. to the parent. You seem to simply want the previous sibling:

```
$(this).prev()
// or if you want to select the previous only if it is a path:
$(this).prev('path');
```

If the element you are looking for is not an immediate sibling, i.e. there are other elements in between, have a look at [jquery find closest previous sibling with class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2310270/218196) , using the tag name instead of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using cloeset

```
 $(this).closest("g").find('path').attr("class", "active");
```

Comment: Note that this will select **all** `path` elements inside `g`, not only the previous siblings.

Comment: Yes you are right but `query selector ` inside `find()`  can be used to find more precisely.  Your answer is better. I have just tried to fix his mistake