# Grab content of closest previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on something which may be called reply to someone post under some kind of article.

Basically, what I want to achieve is when you click 'reply to post' (.comment-reply class) which is under the post - you grab it's author name from .comment-username div and you put it to the textarea. The problem is to target this div and grab its content which I want to put in variable and put later to the textarea. Cannot figure this targeting and grabbing. The basic structure of entry is like this:

```
<div class="comment-block comment-child">
    <div class="comment-info title-small text-bold">
        <div class="push-left">
            <span class="comment-username sm-fc">AUTHOR NAME is here</span>
            <span class="comment-time">some date</span>
        </div>
        <div class="push-right">
            <span class="comment-rating">some int value</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="comment-text">
        Sample text => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="comment-functions">
        <span class="comment-reply title-small text-bold">reply to post</span>
        <span class="comment-rate comment-plus"> + </span>
        <span class="comment-rate comment-minus"> - </span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Furthermore, on the same page will be displayed a lot of posts so I dont want to use IDs for every single post, instead of that I'm using classes which is more clear to me in that case.

I've been trying with `$.prev()`, `$.closest()` but no results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try prevAll( ) ?

Comment: yeah, been trying to follow this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310270/jquery-find-closest-previous-sibling-with-class

but no results

Comment: Are you targeting a div to get the id, or a span?

Comment: Rory McCrossan submitted a really nice way to do it, thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to get the common `.comment-block` container and from there `find()` the `.comment-username` and retrieve the `text()`. Try this:

```
$('.comment-reply').click(function() {
    var username = $(this).closest('.comment-block').find('.comment-username').text();
    // do something with the username here...
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/033t16em/1/)

Comment: works perfectly, can't believe it was really that simple. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With parents(selector) you can:

```
 var name = $(this).parents('.comment-username').text();
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Note that `.comment-username` is not a parent of `.comment-reply` - so this won't find the username value.

Comment: It's true, sorry for not read properly. In another case this works perfectly.