# expanding an inline-block jumps to above row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of articles

```
<section>
<article>1</article>
<article>2</article>
<article>3</article>
....
<article>999</article>
<section>
```

arranged in a grid of three per row

```
section { 
  position: relative 
}
article { 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 33%;
}
```

and I want that they expand horizontally to fully occupy its row when clicked.

so I create an `expanded` class

```
.expanded {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and apply it on click

```
$("article").click(function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass("expanded"); 
});
```

I am almost there, as you can see in the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aqw339r0/1/

When I click on any of the articles they expand to the full width of the row; but the problem is that when I click the first article of a row (except the first row) it "**jumps**" to the row immediately above.

I have tried changing the `position` and `display` attributes of both `article` and `.expanded` but I cannot get the behavior I need. For example: When I change the `position:absolute` of `.expanded`, the blocks 5 and 6, "jump" to the row below. Similar when I remove `display:inline-block` and change to `float:left`.

Do you have any ideas of why this happens and how to correct it?

Comment: what if you remove `position:absolute`? that seems to resolve it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aqw339r0/2/

Comment: @godmode That pushes the other div off-screen; probably not the behavior or visual effect PA. wants.

Comment: @goodmode, yes it apparently solves the problem, but in fact, it creates another; as it flips the behavior, so for the 1st in the row it stays in the same row, but makes the others "jump" to the row below. I'd want to have all the blocks expanded in the same row they already are on.

Comment: I assume that it's impossible to make rows, really? This is, wrap each 3 elements in a position relative box. Can you?

Comment: why this happens is pretty clear...you are changing the document flow

Comment: Oh! Surprise! One answer with the articles wrapped xD . It's very complicated if you don't change the html, but I promise you I will going to search a solution without wrapping

Comment: I think that you can make it with flexbox, but I'm not sure how to achieve the columns, I'm newbie with flexbox. If you put the `section` with `display:flex` you can play with it. A visual guide with a toy to play: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties . Good luck

Comment: You just need to add/remove a blank article element in place of the newly positioned (absolute) element.  See my answer below http://jsfiddle.net/dpL6amh2/

Comment: @Marcos, no I can't, the articles list is generated on the fly, and also when the screen shrinks it does not contain three but only two articles.

Comment: @deebs don't quite get your intention, anyway the fiddle does no solve the problem, the box still jumps.

Comment: @charlietfl yes? I do? why can it be? I just change the styling, not the DOM

Comment: position absolute takes elements out of the document flow

Comment: @PA I didn't understand your initial issue - I thought you didn't want the other boxes (not the selected boxes) to move out of their original position.  I added to Rick's solution and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/guhcwoy1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `position:absolute` is set on an `<article>` element, that takes it out of the normal content flow, and causes the offset. We can correct it by adding an empty `<article>` as a placeholder when the click triggers, and removing it when click again.

```
var open = false;

jQuery("article").click(function () {
    open = !open;

    if (open) {
        $(this).addClass("expanded");
        $(this).before("<article class='holder'>&nbsp;</article>");
    } else {
        $("article").removeClass("expanded");
        $(".holder").remove();
    }
});
```

*p.s. I'm not that good at jQuery, any suggestions are welcome.*

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pemzkvvm/)

Comment: I'm accepting this one, because it helps understand the reason and solves the root cause, eventhough I am implementing a slightly different solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using the solution from @Rick (minus the css top edit) and then toggling an additional element to keep other elements in place, this should do what is needed: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guhcwoy1/)

```
  $("article").click(function() { 
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded"); 
        if ($(this).hasClass("expanded"))
        {
            $(this).before("<article class='blank'>&nbsp;</article>");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).prevAll('.blank').first().remove();
        }
  });
```

To explain further, when the element is clicked:

**if ADDING the class 'expanded'**, then this will also add a blank article element (before) as a placeholder to keep the flow consistent.  This is important because when the element with class 'expanded' becomes position: absolute it is removed from the normal flow of the content.

**if REMOVING the class 'expanded'**, then this will also remove the blank article placeholder element.  The [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) function looks through all previous elements with the class 'blank' and then takes the first() one and removes it.  Because it was inserted 'before', this is guaranteed to remove the correct blank article placeholder.

Comment: Please say more about the `prevAll()` method. Include a simplified example if possible.

Comment: prevAll() method looks through all of the previous elements (in this case with the class "blank").  This solution uses the first() differently, but may explain more in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310270/jquery-find-closest-previous-sibling-with-class

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a pure CSS solution, but since you're using jQuery anyway, simply hard-code the expanded element's `top`:

```
$("article").click(function() { 
  $(this).css('top', $(this).position().top);
  $(this).toggleClass("expanded"); 
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zggmwsr/)

The `top` style will be ignored once the expanded class is removed.

Comment: That's not a pure css solution, but it's simple enough for my needs. Also I like it, because it may help me with another little nasty css problem

Comment: with this solution when you click on "3", the numbered articles below jump up one position each.  Is that okay still?  I didn't understand the issue initially but now I am starting to.

Comment: This uses @Rick's solution with added jQuery to keep other articles in place: http://jsfiddle.net/fn2zv8va/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 <section>
    <article>1</article>
    <article>2</article>
    <article>3</article>
    </section>
    <section>
    <article>4</article>
    <article>5</article>
    <article>6</article>
    <section>
    <section>
    <article>7</article>
    <article>8</article>
    <article>9</article>
    </section>

    section {
        position:relative;
    }

    article { 
        width: 30%;
        min-width: 200px;
        min-height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .expanded {
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#eef;
        left:0px;
        top:0;
        position:absolute;
        transition: 0.2s linear;
    }

    // if you want others to close while expanding
    $("article").click(function(){ 
       $('article').removeClass("expanded");
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded"); 
    });


// esle if you want everything to be expanded
   $("article").click(function(){ 
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded"); 
    });
```

Comment: Hi faisal, a valiant effort, however, you would have done better explaining your goal and addressing specifically the problem.  Also, you can use free tools such as jsFiddle to provide an example. I  won't downvote but others might.