# jquery find previous class and return value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the closest `dropdown-header` when clicking a list item

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 1</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 3</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this isn't working, could someone please explain. Thank you

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
          $(this).parent().parent().find('.dropdown-header').html(); //would return Word #
          e.preventDefault();
      });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310270/jquery-find-closest-previous-sibling-with-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go up a level from the anchor to the list item, then up the list to the list item with the dropdown-header class. Also, .`val()` works for form elements, not list items, so you want `.html()` or `.text()`. Try:

```
var val = $(this).parent().prevAll('.dropdown-header').html();
```

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  var val = $(this).parent().prevAll('.dropdown-header').html(); //would return Word #
  console.log(val)
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 1</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 3</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` alone doesn't work for you in this case as it's intended to search for parents, not siblings of parents.

To fix this You could use `closest()` to get the parent `li`, then `prevAll()` with `:first` to get the element you're looking for. Try this:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).closest('li').prevAll('.dropdown-header:first').text();
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 1</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header">Word 3</li>
  <li><a href="#">Click me 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is necessary, as `prevAll()` would potentially find 3 elements and display the concatenated text of each of them