# jQuery to find parent label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML fragment:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
  <label for="allquestion4" class="col-sm-6 control-label label-red">Question</label>
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select size="2" class="selectpicker" id="allquestion4" title="Choose">
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
</div>
```

Why is the label not being found by the following jQuery:

```
$(this).closest('label').hasClass('.label-red');
```

Where $(this) is the select picker.

**UPDATE**

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalnz/stezu0cr/4/) fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.` from `hasClass('.label-red')`. It wants the name of the class not a CSS selector.

Comment: I removed the . but still not finding it.

Comment: It looks like the label tags must wrap the select tags in order for this to work  https://jsfiddle.net/bigalnz/stezu0cr/11/

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case that `closest()` only looks at parents and not at siblings. Unfortunately, while there is a [general sibling combination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), it can only select an element if it follows the first, not if it precedes. If you don't want to nest the `select`s, perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310270/jquery-find-closest-previous-sibling-with-class) will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the original JQuery selector as pointed out by @Mark remove the `.` from the `hasClass('.label-red')` secondly the selector needs a parent so the html needs to be modified so that the `<label>` tags wrap the `<select>` thus:

```
<label class="col-sm-6 control-label label-red">Question
    <select size="2" class="selectpicker" id="allquestion4" title="Choose">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Or if the html is kept the same navigate to the parent `form-group` and then find like this:

`$(this).closest('.form-group').find('select').hasClass('label-red')`